# ListActivity cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: java, android, eclipse, eclipse-juno

I am new to Android development . While creating a Task reminder application I got stuck at this point where it says "ListActivity cannot be resolved as a type".
I tried to find a solution for this but I couldn't.
This is the full code.

```
package com.android.taskreminder;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;


public class ReminderListActivity extends ListActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.reminder_list);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.reminder_list, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot :D it helped, but now Its giving me an error that R cannot be resolved to a variable.

Comment: Do you have all the layout `xml` files and `menu` files present eg: `reminder_list` in `res/menu` and in `res/layout` ?

Comment: Clean the project and build it

Comment: @SweetWisherツ I tried cleaning the building again but still the errors are there

Comment: @ShobhitPuri yeah there are present

Comment: Is there any error in your project ? Checkconsole

Comment: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimaryDark'.

some error like these

Comment: @Xanzy In which file is that error? So its errors in this file which are stopping the R file to build. Correct those before cleaning the project.

Comment: @ShobhitPuri yeah the errors are in this file and they say reminder_list and action_settings cannot be resolved or is not a field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you missing import statements? Try <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>o</kbd> on windows or try importing `import android.app.ListActivity` manually.